# Android ListView from JSON with Space in string

Tags: android, json, listview

I have this listview and i populate it from json in string, and it work perfectly but when this json contains a space onclick event app crash:

(I have commented where the app crash with some code and image)

```
final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String s = testopass;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ':') {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter > 0) {
            try {
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(testopass);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Iterator<String> iter = jObj.keys();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iter.next();
                    try {
                        Object value = jObj.get(key);
                        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                        datum.put("nome",value.toString());
                        datum.put("cf", key.toString());
                        data.add(datum);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // Something went wrong!
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception er) {

            }

            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    new String[]{"nome", "cf"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1,
                            android.R.id.text2});

            mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

            mylist.setClickable(true);

            mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                    Object o = mylist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    JSONObject jObj = null;
                    try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(o.toString()); //this return error and go to catch
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String cane = "";
                    try {
                        cane = jObj.getString("cf"); //crash is here because jObj is empty
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  


                }

            });

        testopass is a string: `{"12345674":"SPACE CRASH"}`
```

result in app is:

[image]

I have stopped the code:

[image]

The crash is:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 13 of {nome=SPACE CRASH, cf=12345674}
```

How to fix this problem?? Im very very new in android dev

I have a partial solution

```
 jObj = new JSONObject(o.toString().replace("nome=","nome=\"").replace(",","\","));
```

With this code not crash but i think there are better solution?

Comment: You can use GSON  (https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing JSON. This will make your work lot easier

Comment: the problem can be here datum.put("cf", key.toString()); since is not puting the data right, when you try to get it below to pass it to cane you are not getting the value so cane is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your adapter an `JSONObject`. That means that you should not try to decode it as such in the `onItemClick()` method. You are actually passing an `ArrayList` with `Map<String, String>` objects. This means you need to cast to that object.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    String cane = "nothing";
    try {
        String keyName = "cf";

        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if(map.containsKey(keyName)){
            cane = map.get(keyName);
        }
        else{
            Log.e("onItemClick", "Upps no value for: " + keyName);
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
});
```

**___________________________________________________**

**Note:**

In general, it is not recommended to have several `try..catch` blocks in one method **unless** you are doing something in your code to prevent the code to continue with bad data or `null` objects! You have several examples in your code, where you simply log your errors, but then you would (if an error occurred) continue in that method with `null` objects. Example:

```
try {
    //if an **error** occurs **HERE**....
    jObj = new JSONObject(testopass);
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // You must do something **HERE** to get things straight **OR** **EXIT**
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //... you continue **HERE** with a **null** object jObj!!
    Iterator<String> iter = jObj.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) { 
    //....
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, perfect solution =)